# What is the purpose of kernel module "hyperv_fb" in 'el7uek.x86_64' kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

What is the purpose of kernel module  "hyperv_fb" in 'el7uek.x86_64' kernel?

`[root@app1 fg]# lsmod | grep _fb
hyperv_fb              20480  1 
hv_vmbus              540672  6 hyperv_keyboard,hv_netvsc,hid_hyperv,hv_utils,hyperv_fb,hv_storvsc`

Answer (score 3):

You're running under [Microsoft Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/index) and all of its [emulation & interfacing modules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/Supported-Linux-and-FreeBSD-virtual-machines-for-Hyper-V-on-Windows) are loaded. `hyperv_fb` will be providing a framebuffer device for drawing to the screen.